# Omit Digit Method Bug

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I'm having an issue with a method that creates an array of consecutive digits (i.e. if you input 1 and 10 as an argument, the array will include every number from 1-10), and then compares each number to another digit (e.g. 4) - if the numbers match (e.g. 4 == 4), then it removes that number from the array. Finally it returns that array.

I've implemented the method below which works sometimes, but not all the time and I'm not sure why?

For example, if I created a new array and printed each array:

```
ArrayList<Integer> omittedDigitArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(Omit.allIntegersWithout(20, 45, 3));

        System.out.println("Array - Numbers with Omitted Digit:");
        for (int n : omittedDigitArray) {
            System.out.print(n + ", ");
        }
```

The number 29 is omitted from the array? Could anyone tell me why please? Thanks!

```
    // Creates the ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Loop creates an array of numbers starting at "from" ending at "to"
    for (int i = from; i < to + 1; i++) {
        numberList.add(i);
    }

    // Check the array to see whether number contains digit
    // Code checks whether x contains 5, n == one digit

    // IMPORTANT: Doesn't work on the first half of numbers i.e / will remove 3 but not 30
    for (int j = 0; j < numberList.size(); j++) {

        int number = (int) numberList.get(j);         // This can be any integer
        int thisNumber = number >= 0 ? number: -number;    // if statement in case argument is negative
        int thisDigit;

        while (thisNumber != 0) {

            thisDigit = thisNumber % 10;    // Always equal to the last digit of thisNumber
            thisNumber = thisNumber / 10;   // Always equal to thisNumber with the last digit chopped off, or 0 if thisNumber is less than 10

            if (thisDigit == omittedDigit) {
                numberList.remove(j);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the completed Array list
    return numberList;
}
```

}

Comment: When you're removing items from a List, you should iterate backwards through the list.  That way, you don't have to adjust the List index counter.  Also, your instructions don't say if the digit is in the number.  Your instructions say if the numbers match.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop has a problem. Once you remove an element from the list, you should break from that loop. Otherwise you might remove unrelated additional numbers (if the omitted digit appears several times in the same number).

```
    while (thisNumber != 0) {

        thisDigit = thisNumber % 10;    // Always equal to the last digit of thisNumber
        thisNumber = thisNumber / 10;   // Always equal to thisNumber with the last digit chopped off, or 0 if thisNumber is less than 10

        if (thisDigit == omittedDigit) {
            numberList.remove(j);
            j--;
            break; // add this
        }
    }
```

I ran your code (+ my suggested fix) with a range of 1 to 50 and omitted digit 4 and got :

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 50]
```

The problem in your code occurs when 44 is being processed - after you remove it (due to the first 4, you continue the while loop, find another 4 and remove another number, which happens to be 39, since the numbers 40 to 43 were already removed).

Answer (score 0):

My suggested solution:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Loop creates an array of numbers starting at "from" ending at "to"
    for (int i = from; i < to + 1; i++) {
        numberList.add(i);
    }
//removing all numbers that contain the digit
    numberList.removeIf(j->containsDigit(j,thisDigit));
    return numberList;
}

boolean containsDigit(int number,int thisDigit){
    //making sure thisDigit is positive
    thisDigit=Math.abs(thisDigit)

    //if thisDigit is not a digit result is false
    if(thisDigit>=10) return false;

    //breaking the number into its digits
    List<Integer> digits=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(number>0){
        digits.add(number%10);
        number=(int) number/10;
    }

    return digits.contains(thisDigit);
}
```